# Plotting a paraboloid and a plane

Tags: plotting

I am trying to visualize the intersection of a paraboloid and and a plane.
My paraboloid is of the form $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^\top A x - b^\top x$$
where $x$ is a vector and $A$ is the pd matrix
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2\\ 2 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$
and 
$$b = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -8 \end{bmatrix}$$
My plane is parameterised as $$x^{t+1} = x^t + \alpha (b -Ax^t)$$

Basically my plane corresponds to a line search to choose $\alpha$ to minimize $f$ along a line.

I plotted the function $f$ using Plot3D, but I do not know how to plot the plane and contours.

My code so far is just plotting the function

```
Plot3D[1.5 x^2 + 2  x y + 3 y^2 + 2 x - 8 y, {x, -4,4}, {y, -4,4}]
```

I am not sure how to plot the plane corresponding to

$x^{t+1} = x^t + \alpha (b -Ax^t)$

Comment: What did you do? show your code.

Comment: @AlexTrounev.  i edited the question.

Comment: There is no plane equation. Usually in geometry used $ax+by+cz+d=0$. In Mathematica used `InfinitePlane[{p1,p2,p3}] ` or  `InfinitePlane[{p1, {v1,v2}}] `.